# Remove code lines from code published in HTML

Tags: html, ide, editor

Sometimes code is published in "nice" form with line numbers. It is very inconvenient if you need just copy/paste it to your project. How to copy code lines from HTML page without line numbers?

[Sample](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/22/raspberry-pi-raspbian-getting-started-sdl-2/) with code line numbers:

[image]

Comment: You could copy and paste it, then use regex to replace it with empty space: `/^\d+/g` (starts with at least one digit)

Comment: If there is a number in the code, then this can cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, it's really annoying.
I can suggest a trick.

Right click on the number, click inspect.
You will have class assigned to the number, add display:none to it.
Now number will be hidden.

[image]